# Can you measure css borders in %s?

Tags: css

I want to make my borders be percentages because my whole layout is based on percentages and when the screen is small enough one part floats lower because the borders are too big in px.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/s9BDG/1/)

Comment: This is the code: http://goo.gl/AHvEH

Comment: Put it in the question next time!

Comment: @Eric, I commented it because it was after I had created the question and I wanted people to notice it.

Answer (score 2):

If I read the specs right, it is [valid in CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-width):

> Percentages:  width* of containing block

It seems to be **invalid** in CSS 1 and [2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties):

> Percentages:     N/A

therefore, I wouldn't trust it to be supported across all browsers right now.

Comment: The question is which browsers support percentages and which don't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-width

The % value is based on the width of containing block if the containing block has a horizontal text mode, otherwise the height.

**Browser-compatibility:** Nonexistent.
It doesn't work in any of the browsers that I have: IE9 beta, FF 4 beta 7, Opera 10,63, latest Chrome and Safari.

Comment: True, but note that this seems to be new in CSS3

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't use percentages for border width, at least not reliably, as Pekka and Sime points out.

<strike>yes, you could use a percentage for a border, but its highly unorthodox,</strike> the problem is probably elsewhere in your layout.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Tried it out with Chrome 9.0.587.0 dev.

Comment: @chromedude: try this: http://csseasy.com/layouts/fluid/2column_left.html its will give you a two column fluid layout

Comment: @chromedude: if you want a fixed-width layout, try this: http://csseasy.com/layouts/fixed/2column_left.html

Comment: @thejh It turns out that it doesn't work in any current browser.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be valid in CSS3, but not in CSS2.

CSS2's box model says [border width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties) is of [`length`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length) type, and:

> The format of a length value (denoted
>   by `<length>` in this specification) is
>   a `<number>` (with or without a decimal
>   point) immediately followed by a unit
>   identifier (e.g., `px`, `em`, etc.). After
>   a zero length, the unit identifier is
>   optional.

Also note that [percentages](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#percentage-units) are not the same thing and are discussed in the very next section.

Now, browsers fully supporting CSS3 are few and far between. You might not want to exceedingly rely on that feature.

Comment: édéric **All** modern browsers support CSS3... to a certain degree.

Comment: @Šime, I suppose that whenever IE9 comes out, you'll be right ;)

Comment: édéric List of CSS3 features implemented in IE8: @font-face (partially), indirect adjacent (a ~ b) selector, several attribute selectors (^=, $=, *=, ns|), overflow-x and overflow-y (partially), word-wrap, text-justify, writing-mode, box-sizing, ruby-position, ruby-align, ruby-overhang, SVG color keywords, transparent (value) (partially). IE8 does support CSS3.

Comment: @Šime, heh, you're right, I should have said `fully supporting CSS3` :) Answer updated.

Comment: édéric **No** browser fully supports CSS3, and **no browser ever will**. There will always be some tiny details in the standard that a given browser will not support. The idea is that you stop saying "browser X supports standard Y", because that statement doesn't have any value. The 32 CSS3 standards contain probably several thousand distinct features, and any given browser supports some of those features, and some others not. The same thing applies to HTML5 - some people say that a certain browser "supports HTML5" compared to another browser which doesn't.